# Sql SELECT for personnel available in a specific time period

Tags: sql, date, multiple-tables

I have 3 tables. First one is a list of personnel:

Table `Personnel`

```
Id_personnel         Name
1                    John
2                    Alice
3                    Tom
4                    Charles
5                    Ben
```

Second is a table with medical leave:

Table `Medical`

```
Id_personnel         Start_date         End_date
3                    2012-08-02         2012-08-05
2                    2012-08-02         2012-08-15
4                    2012-10-04         2012-10-06
2                    2012-10-02         2012-10-15
2                    2012-09-20         2012-09-21
```

Third is a table with holiday leave:

Table `Holiday`

```
Id_personnel         Start_date         End_date
3                    2012-08-02         2012-08-05
2                    2012-02-02         2012-02-15
5                    2012-10-01         2012-10-05
```

I have two event dates: `Symposium_start_date` and a `Symposium_end_date` (as variables) and I would like to select all `Personnel.Id_personnel` and `Personnel.Name` available for the symposium (not in medical leave or on holiday).

In my example if `Symposium_start_date = 2012-10-02` and `Symposium_end_date = 2012-10-06` the result must be:

```
Id_personnel         Name
1                    John
3                    Tom
```

(as you can see Alice and Charles are on medical leave and Ben on holiday)

Thank you!

Comment: For this type of query you must specify the database. Date overlapping is handled differently by Oracle and MS SQL Server and others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a MS SQL server.

```
declare @start date = '2012-10-02', @end date = '2012-10-10'

select personnel.* 
from personnel
    left join holiday on personnel.Id_personnel = holiday.Id_personnel
        and holiday.start_date<=@end
        and holiday.end_date>=@start
    left join medical on personnel.Id_personnel= medical.Id_personnel
        and medical.start_date<=@end
        and medical.end_date>=@start
where holiday.Id_personnel is null  
and medical.Id_personnel is null
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming MS-SQL, similar to others, but have shown tables unioned together, and subquery that shows all those who conflict with the symposium dates - I think this is easier to write first - and then selecting all those people who are NOT conflicting.  Regards!

```
declare @Symposium_start_date date = '2012-10-02'
declare @Symposium_end_date date = '2012-10-06'

select * from Personnel P where p.Id_personnel not in (
    select Id_personnel from (
        select m.Id_personnel, m.Start_date, m.End_date
        from Medical M 
        union
        select h.Id_personnel, h.Start_date, h.End_date
        from Holiday H 
    ) as Leave
    where (Start_date  between @Symposium_start_date and @Symposium_end_date)
        or (End_date between @Symposium_start_date and @Symposium_end_date)
        or (Start_date <= @Symposium_start_date and End_date >= @Symposium_end_date)
)
```

Comment: What if the person's holiday starts befoe the symposium and ends after it?

Comment: Very true, have added that now.

Comment: And @podiluska, I like your date selection approach better than mine!

Comment: @podiluska - thank you :))) yes, both are elegant and useful. I will use podiluska's solution because I see it more easy to customize (my question was only the "core" of the problem - each table has other fields I have to filter).

Answer (score 0):

this is an example with the Medical table only. You can easily add the Holiday

```
declare @Symposium_start_date datetime
declare @Symposium_end_date  datetime

set @Symposium_start_date = '2012-08-01'
set @Symposium_end_date  = '2012-08-04'


select * 
from personel p left join medical m on p.Id_personel = m.Id_personel
where (@Symposium_start_date > m.end_date) or (@Symposium_end_date<m.start_date)
```